# Loading a SQL script from within another SQL script in H2 database

Tags: sql, database, h2, dbcommand

Is it possible to include sql files within another sql file in H2 database.

I have 5 sql files

```
1) create-tables.sql
2) insert-data.sql
   1) data-1.sql
   2) data-2.sql
   3) data-3.sql
```

In this example i want to include **data-1.sql**, **data-2.sql**, **data-3.sql** within **insert-data.sql**

> testProperty.connection.driverClass=org.h2.Driver
> testProperty.connection.url=jdbc:h2:file:./target/db/testdb;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;INIT=runscript
> from 'src/test/resources/sql/**create-tables.sql**'\;runscript from
> 'src/test/resources/sql/**insert-data.sql**'
> testProperty.connection.username=sa testProperty.connection.password=

I have tried the following commands in **insert-data.sql**, but not working

```
\source data-1.sql
@data-1.sql
\include data-1.sql
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no directives is SQL scripts for H2. But you can run the same `RUNSCRIPT` command from a script launched with this command:

`src/test/resources/sql/insert-data.sql`:

```sql
RUNSCRIPT FROM 'src/test/resources/sql/data-1.sql';
-- commands
```

`src/test/resources/sql/data-1.sql`:

```sql
-- commands
```

Please note that relative paths will be treated as relative to the current working directory of the process and not as relative to the script with this command.